# pytest ImportError while importing test module, make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I'm looking to test logic that invokes a lambda to fetch an object from S3, however when running tests via pytest, I get the following error:

```
ImportError while importing test module /path/to/test_handler.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.

Traceback:
\python3.10\latest\lib\importlib\__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
src\keys\test_handler.py:7: in <module>
    from handler import LambdaS3ResourceClass
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'handler'
```

I cannot seem to find a consistent answer for the root cause of this error. Some people suggest to add `__init__.py` files, some suggest to remove them.

I am very new to Python so I am wondering if I am missing something basic with respect to module naming or perhaps how the python path determines what file to use for references as it seems to be importing `test_handler.py` instead of the actual `handler` module. Also wondering if this could be related to intellij setup or if the pytest hint is a red herring altogether.

Project structure is as follows:

```
|-- public-key-fetcher
    |-- src
        |-- keys
            |-- __init__.py
            |-- handler.py
            |-- test_handler.py
        |-- __init__.py
    |-- Makefile
    |-- poetry.toml
    |-- poetry.lock
    |-- pyproject.toml
```

```
# handler.py

from os import environ

from boto3 import resource, client

# Initialize the resource once per Lambda execution environment by using global scope.
_LAMBDA_S3_RESOURCE = {
    "resource": resource('s3'),
    "bucket_name": environ.get("PUBLIC_KEYS_BUCKET")
}


class LambdaS3ResourceClass:
    def __init__(self, lambda_s3_resource):
        self.resource = lambda_s3_resource["resource"]
        self.bucket_name = lambda_s3_resource["bucket_name"]
        self.bucket = self.resource.Bucket(self.bucket_name)


def fetch_keys(event, context):
    # Do something
```

```
# test_handler.py

import os

from boto3 import resource, client
from moto import mock_lambda
from moto import mock_s3

from handler import LambdaS3ResourceClass


@mock_s3
@mock_lambda
class TestLambda:
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.test_s3_bucket_name = "unit_test_s3_bucket"
        os.environ["S3_BUCKET_NAME"] = self.test_s3_bucket_name

        s3_client = client('s3', region_name="us-east-1")
        s3_client.create_bucket(Bucket=self.test_s3_bucket_name)

        s3_client.put_object(Bucket="mockBucket", Key="dummy-oidc.json", Body="abc")

        mocked_s3_resource = {"resource": resource('s3'),
                              "bucket_name": self.test_s3_bucket_name}

        self.mocked_s3_class = LambdaS3ResourceClass(mocked_s3_resource)

    def test_fetch_keys(self):
        body = self.mocked_s3_class.bucket.Object("dummy-oidc.json").get()['Body'].read()
        assert body == "abc"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try starting pytest with the option `--import-mode=importlib`

pytest's import logic is slightly different from standard python's import. Don't ask for details, I wonder if there is anyone who fully understands this. :o

See also https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/explanation/pythonpath.html

Best, Frank

Comment: I solved the problem by importing the relative path of the handler in the test file, however it doesn't really make sense to me as I would think that them being in the same directory would provide that as is.


I think there might have been some sort of shadowing conflict with a different module which had the same exact underlying directory structure.


Thanks for posting the link, will give it a read!